# Can I program OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY to trigger based on external verifiable events?

Tags: multi-signature, checklocktimeverify

Can OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY and multi-sig be used to trigger a transaction based on external verifiable events?

Some potential uses I have in mind:

- Death
- College graduation of a child or grandchild
- Issuance of building permits
- Yearly net company profits exceeding a certain threshold
- Deposit refund after verification that vacation rental property is undamaged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not with OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY, as it is not possible to consume an external input with that particular operation. But you can write a third-party oracle that will release some secret (i.e. a hash) based on the set of potential use-cases you have suggested, so the beneficiary could redeem the funds promised on the fulfillments of the condition.

A contract similar to that of a [Hashed-Timelock Contract (HTLC)](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2015-July/000021.html) should be useful in this situation.